# bootstrap positioning a graphic element

Tags: jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a website that has graphic placement of images in the header problem.  I am using html5 along with bootstrap version 3. First image places well (of course).  Textual part centers well, like I want it to.  Its the right side graphic element that I am having a problem with.  I can get the graphic to move towards the right and up, but when I do that it remains outside of my grandparent div container class.  I need the graphic to remain within the div .container but reside within the right side of it.  I have tried styling with relative position and using  a style of right: 0.5em, but that does not work.  I am working with modernizr in the head element along with bootstrap3 css call.  jQuery and bootstrap.js linked towards the bottom of the html file.  I have tried the render in IE and Chrome and both act the same stupid way.  Any suggestions??

```
<div class='container'>
    <header class='hidden-xs hidden-sm' style='height: 150px'>
      <img src='assets/media/tigerLogo.png' alt='Norman High School logo' style='padding-top: 0.5em' class='pull-left' />
      <h1 class='text-center'>Tiger Baseball</h1>
      <img src='assets/media/swingBatta.png' alt='Tiger swinging a bat graphic' class='pull-right' />
    </header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
      <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainMenu">
          <span class="sr-only" href="#mainContent">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand visible-xs visible-sm" href="#">Tiger Baseball</a>
      </div>
      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse" id="mainMenu">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Photos</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Homerun Club</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Support</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Shop</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">News&#47;Events</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Schedules</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Rosters</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Coaches</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Archives</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <section id='mainContent' role='main'>
      <article></article>
      <aside></aside>
    </section>
    <footer>
      <p>Powered by: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</p>
      <div id='sponsorAds' class='well well-sm'>
        <p>whose your daddy</p>
      </div>
    </footer>
  </div><!-- site container-->
```

I have a online active testing site at serco-hrc.com/rickTest/index.html.

Comment: Hey, welcome to Stackoverflow. Could you maybe give a visual example of what you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

You could rearrange your DOM elements so the floated element appears aligned with your non-floated element like so:

```
<header class="hidden-xs hidden-sm" style="height: 180px;">
  <img src="assets/media/tigerLogo.png" alt="Norman High School logo" style="padding-top: 0.5em" class="pull-left">
  <img src="assets/media/swingBatta.png" alt="Tiger swinging a bat graphic" class="pull-right">
  <h1 class="text-center">Tiger Baseball</h1>
</header>
```